# ASP.net MVC missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am following a guide to learn Asp.net MVC5.
I have created solution with three project and with NuGet i have installed this library:

> Install-Package Ninject -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
>
> Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
>
> Install-Package Ninject.MVC5 -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
>
> Install-Package Ninject -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
>
> Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
>
> Install-Package Ninject.MVC5 -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
>
> Install-Package Moq -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
>
> Install-Package Moq -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc -projectname SportsStore.Domain
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc -projectname
>   SportsStore.UnitTests

Then i have added reference and i had this:

[image]

I have problem with class NinjectDependencyResolver.cs precisly into method AddBindings():

```
private void AddBindings() {
        Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> {
                    new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },
                    new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },
                    new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }
                    });
        kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);

    }
```

where I have binded my Interface IProductRepository and my class Products to Mock. I reiceived this error:

> missing a using directive or an assembly reference

I have checked into reference of SportsStore and I noticed that the reference were already there.

I have tried to import class with using:

```
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;
```

but didn't work, furthermore when i typed SportsStore intellisense suggested me the folder Abstract, therefore i had SportsStore.Abstract but then intellisense when I have put dot after Abstract it didn't suggest me nothing, it seemed like intellisense didn't find Interface IProductRepository. The same thing is happened when i have typed SportStore.Entities, intellisense didn't suggest me class Product why?
Why i had error:  missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I have tried:

Clean Project and then Build or Rebuild project but didn't work.

Comment: Check the namespaces for each project

Comment: What's the error when you build the solution?

Comment: How i check namespace for each project? I have this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IProductRepository' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SportsStore.WebUI C:\Users\Fra\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs 25 Active

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I have solved the problem was:

The class Product into folder Entities wasn't public therefore i have changed to public, after the change i could enter to class. Then i have tried to change Interface into folder Abstract to Public but despite everything i could not access from an other projec to class, therefore i have created a new public class and then i have changed the attribute class to Interface and now work all.

Answer (score 0):

Chcek if you have all references at your projects. It solved this problem for me.
To add the reference to your project, click on the project -> add -> reference and there check boxes near project you want to use.